# How can I get a low rate loan for my house as a retiree?

Tags: united-states, loans, home-loan

I am 80 years old in need of a loan.  I wish to use my house as a collateral, but don't know how to go about it.  I live in Texas, United States.  How long does it take to get a low interest loan?  And what are the key points to look out for?

Answer (score 6):

A key factor here:  Part of the process is looking at your income.  At 80 your income is probably fixed and simply meeting your expenses.  If you're in the position of needing a loan why would they think you would be in a position to repay the loan?

I strongly suspect you would be better served by a reverse mortgage in some form.  You don't repay it ever, it comes out of the value of your house when you die.